# Logstash shutdows after start

Tags: twitter, logstash, elastic-stack

im new on the ELK Stack and i can't figure out why Logstash keeps shutdown after i execute it. I'm trying to gather information from twitter.[image: Logstash shutdown]

```
input {
  twitter {
    consumer_key => "XXX"
    consumer_secret => "XXX"
    oauth_token => "XXX"
    oauth_token_secret => "XXX"
    keywords => ["portugal", "game", "movie"]
    ignore_retweets => true
    full_tweet => true
  }
}

filter {}

output{
  stdout {
    codec => dots
        }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "twitterind"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your config file located in the bin directory? Try to pass the full path, `logstash.bat -f c:\full\path\to\your\config\file.conf`

Comment: @leandrojmp my conf file is in config, i passed the full path same error. I followed the docs, Logstash References Running on Windows, but fails

Comment: And what is the error when you tried the command from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash-windows.html#running-logstash-windows-manual)? This error that you got in your is because logstash can't find your config filed, since you ran it from the `bin` directory and your config is in another directory. Try the documentation command and update your question with the result.

Comment: @leandrojmp it seems like it was indeed a matter of directory, **thank you**. The correct command should be `logstash -f ..\config\twitter.conf`.Seems like the tutorial i was following was wrong.Don´t know how i lost so much time for a simple thing.